# TensorFlow ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a code that loads spectogram data from .npy files using a custom generator using the `from_generator` function. When I start training the network the error I get is as mentioned in the title.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 99, 43, 1), found shape=(99, 43, 1)
```

The spectogram numpy array files are in the following shape: `99,43,1`.

Generator code:

```
def train_dataset_gen():
    for index, file_name in enumerate(train_dataset): 
        X_train[index] = np.load(path + file_name)   
        Y_train[index] = file_name[0:1]
        
        X_train[index] = np.expand_dims(X_train[index], axis=0)
         
        yield X_train[index], Y_train[index]
        
gen_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    train_dataset_gen,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.uint8),
    output_shapes=((99,43,1), tuple())).repeat(count=-1)

gen_train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_dataset)).batch(batch_size)
```

Model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(4, 3, 
           padding='same',
           activation='relu',
           kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
           name='conv_layer1',
           input_shape=(99, 43, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D(name='max_pooling1', pool_size=(2,2)),
    Conv2D(4, 3, 
           padding='same',
           activation='relu',
           kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
           name='conv_layer2'),
    MaxPooling2D(name='max_pooling3', pool_size=(2,2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(
        80,
        activation='relu',
        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
        name='hidden_layer1'
    ),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(
        len(command_words), 
        activation='softmax',
        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
        name='output'
    )
])
```

Model fit:

```
history = model.fit(
    gen_train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=gen_validate_dataset,
    validation_steps=10,
)
```

Thank you for any suggestions!!

**Tried:**
To try to add the missing `None` column I added the `X_train[index] = np.expand_dims(X_train[index], axis=0)` and although the generator data changed to the shape of (None, 99, 43, 1), the error persists.

Comment: This None is for the batch_size and your data is not batched why? when doing this gen_train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_dataset)).batch(batch_size)
this is not an in place function you have to assign this to a variable like this
gen_train_dataset = gen_train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_dataset)).batch(batch_size)
The final remark is to add the batch_size, it is just expecting your batch_size which is not given.

Comment: remove np.expand(x_train[index], axis=0) from your code, you don't need this, just batch your data like I said before. gen_train_dataset = gen_train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_dataset)).batch(batch_size)

Comment: Thank you @MohammadAhmed that makes a lot of sense. A stupid mistake on my side.

Comment: I am posting this answer, kindly upvote it.

Comment: Absolutely, please do!:)

Comment: It has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gen_train_dataset = gen_train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_dataset)).batch(batch_size)
```